# Не выводит результат mysqli_fetch_array в printf

Tags: php, mysql

Соединении  с базой установлено. Таблица data есть. title тоже в таблице есть и значение не пустое. В чём может быть дело?

```
       <?php
        $result = mysqli_query ("SELECT * FROM data");
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array ($result);
        do {
            printf ('
                <p>%s</p>
                ', $data["title"]);
            }
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
        ?>
```

Comment: покажите что возвращает $data (var_dump($data))

Comment: NULL. ни чего нет почему то ...

Comment: вот вам и ответ

Comment: Больше вопросов чем ответов... Что же с ней не так.

Comment: проверьте все переменные, а после подключение к бд

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM data");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Не помогло...Код вроде аналогичен моему?) записан просто программистом)Могут ли быть проблемы в верстке, которые мешают отображению?

Comment: @Олег у вас вероятно в другом месте ошибка